# Exceptions handling guidelines for C++

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

I understand benefits of using exceptions handling in C++ and I'm aware that it may be tricky. One of rule says, that every function may throw. Ok, but there are situations, where we want to make sure, that function does not throw. I'm looking for any well-known practices or guidelines for handling such situations. Examples:

```
try
{
    // do something
}
catch (std::runtime_error& error)
{
    save_log (error);
    emit_dbus_signal (error);
}
```

I don't care if `save_log()` or `emit_dbus_signal()` will fail, I only want to make sure, that I tried to call them.

```
ThreadPool thread_pool;
SocketsPool socket_pool;
MainLoop main_loop;

try
{
    thread_pool.init ();
    socket_pool.init ();

    main_loop.run ();
}
catch (std::runtime_error& error)
{
    save_log (error);
    emit_dbus_signal (error);
}

thread_pool.finalize ();
socket_pool.finalize ();
```

I only want to make sure, that I tried to finalize `thread_pool` and `socket_pool`. Any error during finalization process should be handled inside `finalize()` methods.

I can remember, which functions does not throw, but it will work only for small programs. Should I add suffix like `_nothrow` to such "non throwing" functions' names and handle this while writing code? Exceptions specification is deprecated since C++11 so I want to avoid it. What about `noexcept`? I still not sure if I understand this new feature. Is it what I'm looking for?

There's no excpetions checking at compile time in C++11 right?

Or maybe I'm completely wring? :)

Comment: Book suggestion:  "Exceptional C++" by Herb Sutter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to understand [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) as a starting point.

Once you're using RAII correctly, you'll find that most of the case where you thought you needed to manually finalize objects have magically disappeared: And, so in a lot of cases, that means you can dispense with the try/catch/finalize approach entirely.

As others have said, you're still going to want your `save_log/emit_dbus_signal` calls in a catch statement somewhere...

In the above case, ThreadPool's constructor would call init(), and the destructor would call finalize().

Comment: `s/catch/finally/`. `catch` doesn't go away with RAII; the need for the hypothetical `finally` block does.

Comment: What if I need to finalize objects in specific order?

Comment: Objects are always destructed in the opposite order to the order in which they were constructed.

Comment: @Alan: sure? wasn't that in the opposite order to the order in which they were _declared_?

Comment: @sehe correct, however in this case they are both the same order.

Comment: @sehe, no, it's always in the reverse order of their construction, with the subtle exception of binding a temporary to a reference, in which case the lifetime of the temporary gets extended.

Comment: @Tomalak, agreed, sort of... The 'catch' is turning the following lines into a 'finally' block. (which of course the standard doesn't support...)

Comment: @Roddy: Right, but as I said, the need for `catch` doesn't go away: it's also performing functions that should only occur when an exception is caught. Of course, that's its job. You want it to do this job whether you're using RAII or not, because otherwise you aren't handling any of your exceptions.

Comment: @avakar - good question: I've never wanted to log exceptions in this way. For my 'own' exceptions I'd do it in the constructor of the exception object. That way you log when they're raised, instead of when they're caught. But, you're always going to need a few 'catch' statements somewhere.

Comment: @sehe It is interesting that the standard defines the order of destruction related to the order of declaration for objects with automatic storage duration, given that declaration and definition are the same in this case, and for objects with storage duration (within a single translation unit) the order is based on the *definition*

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: thanks for digging up the details there. I agree it is '_interesting_' (I can keep my mental model unchanged, fortunately)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Isn't it just the natural order, in which the objects are located on the stack?

Answer (score 3):

You should certainly document which functions are guaranteed not to throw, don't just "remember"!

A common example is that `swap` functions should be no-throw. In that case, there's no reason to put `nothrow` in the name, it's fairly fundamental that many uses of `swap` need to be nothrow. You could likewise make a rule for your project that `log` functions never throw. But this still needs to be documented. Ideally, every function should document what it throws and why, but failing that every function should certainly document what level of exception guarantee it offers, and "nothrow" is the strongest level.

If I had throwing and non-throwing versions of the same functionality, then personally I'd put `nothrow` in the name to distinguish them. Other than that, see what the code looks like. It's possible you'll find yourself writing a piece of code in which you call seven functions in a row, all of which have to be nothrow for the code to be correct. It would probably be helpful to future readers not to have to go and check the declaration of each of those functions to make sure it really doesn't throw, although IDEs help with that. They certainly don't want to have to read 7 doc files if that's avoidable. In that case, I suppose it might be helpful to have Hungarian-style warts in the function names, but that kind of thing can rapidly get out of hand and make the code harder to read, not easier.

Also, if you use a naming convention then operator overloads become rather difficult - you can't distinguish between a throwing and non-throwing `operator+` by name.

Empty exceptions specifications are OK, and C++11 `noexcept` is probably better. Aside from their meaning to the compiler, they help with documentation. It's non-empty exception specifications that are troublesome.

I agree with what everyone is saying about `finalize`: that's what destructors are for.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you actually intend on doing. When you say that you do not care whether `save_log` or `emit_dbus_signal` fails, you are not saying what *don't care* means. That is, if `save_log` fails, do you want to still try and `emit_dbus_signal`? If so, you can:

```
catch ( std::runtime_error& error ) {
   try { save_log( error ); } catch (...) {}
   try { emit_dbus_signal( error ); } catcn ( ... ) {}
}
```

If you do not care about `emit_dbus_signal` not being called if `save_log` fails, another approach would be enclosing the whole `try/catch` inside a second `try/catch`:

```
try {
   try {
     // current code
   } catch ( std::runtime_error const & error ) {
     // current handling
   }
} catch (...) {} // ensure that no other exception escapes either the try or the catch blocks
thread_pool.finalize();
socket_pool.finalize();
```

There are actually other approaches, like using a RAII to ensure that `threadpool.finalize()` is called regardless of how the function completes in the lines of [ScopeGuard](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184403758).

Answer (score 0):

For the finalization functions, you should consider using wrapper classes with the RAII principle instead, that is, rewrite your code using:

```
try {
    initialized_thread_pool pool = thread_pool.init();
} catch (std::runtime_error& error) { handle(error); }
```

and do the finalization in the destructor of initialized_thread_pool.

Once you get that principle right, exception specifications don't seem that much of an issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on RAII
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

If your function throws, any stack variables in that function will still have their destructors called.  That means you can simply call `finalize()` inside the `~ThreadPool()` and `~SocketPool()` destructors.

If you can't modify the ThreadPool or SocketPool classes, you can write your own wrapper classes that call finalize on destruction, e.g.

```
class ScopedThreadPool
{
public:
    ScopedThreadPool(ThreadPool &threadPool) : m_threadPool(threadPool) {}
    ~ScopedThreadPool() { m_threadPool.finalize(); }

private:
    ThreadPool &m_threadPool;
};
```

And then use it like this...

```
ThreadPool threadPool;
ScopedThreadPool scopedThreadPool(threadPool);
```

When the function exits (either via `return` or `throw`) then the `ScopedThreadPool` destructor will call `finalize()` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add `throw()` to the end of a function declaration. The compiler (gcc at least) will then complain if the function throws exceptions.

```
void function() throw();
```

This is standard C++ that says this function doesn't throw any exceptions.  Previously you could say which exceptions it threw, but I think C++11 removed that feature. Only the empty clause, as above, remains.